# Next.js .env variables are not loaded for server-side code

Tags: next.js

As [next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) says, we can use `.env` and `.env.local` and `.env.production` variables in nextjs. And it says that if we don't prefix varibales with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`, then we only have access to them in our server-side code. I have created this configuration:

inside `.env`

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_BRAND=Awesome Product
NEXT_PUBLIC_SLOGAN=This product changes your life, LOL
BOT_EMAIL_USER=product.bot.user@gmail.com
BOT_EMAIL_RECIPIENTS=employee1@company.tld,employee2@company.tld
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=https://api.product.local/
```

inside `.env.local`, which is added to `.gitignore`:

```
BOT_EMAIL_PASSWORD=very_seucre_password_here
```

And inside `.env.production`

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=https://api.product.tld
```

Everything works in development. But in spite of adhering to the docs, I get `undefined` for `BOT_EMAIL_USER` and other variables that are not prefixed with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` in production.

And I don't want to expose those variables to the client, thus I don't prefix them with that.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I fix this?

Comment: If you are in production, why don't you use [the environment variables](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables) for production?

Comment: I'm not using Vercel for my hosting. Also, the philosophy behind `.env` is that it's shared between all environments. I don't want to repeat myself.

Comment: I can still use `NEXT_PUBLIC_X` variables that are in `.env` file in my production environment. Only those variables that are not prefixed don't show.

Comment: _"Only those variables that are not prefixed don't show"_ - And where are you accessing those variables from? Client or server?

Comment: @juliomalves, server-side. The are credentials of a Gmail account that is used to send emails for the **contact us** form. They are used in api routes of next.js.

Comment: Does the `.env.production` file only contain that single environment variable? You need to set them all there too.